# How to modify django-rest-framework API

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I have an [API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm6aC.png). I want to change it so it will look like so:

```
[
    cats: [{
            "id": 1,
            "description": "I lost my mind",
            "petName": "kappies",
            "phone": 56765665464
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "description": "I lost my dog somewhere",
            "petName": "Doggy",
            "phone": 38093716438
        }
    ],
    dogs: [{
            "id": 3,
            "description": "",
            "petName": "",
            "phone": 0
        }, 
        {
            "id": 3,
            "description": "",
            "petName": "",
            "phone": 0
        }
    ]
]
```

Who knows how can I do it?

Do I need to create API for cats and dogs separately?

sry for cups.
[serializers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4ucC.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you found any of the answers useful you should consider up-vote and select the correct answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you got `type` field in your model.

You can then do something like so in your `view.py`:

```
posts = models.Post.objects.all()
posts_serializer = serializers.PostSerializer(posts, many=True)

output = {}
for post in posts_serializer.data:
    type = output.get(post['type'], [])
    output[type].append(post)

return Response(output)
```

You should add more code and what you tried to do next time you are asking a question.

Good Luck